# address of elements of structure of different types

Tags: c++

i want  to find address of elements of structure in memory
here is my code

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct B{
int k;
float t;
char s;
unsigned int m;
long q;
double x;
unsigned long z;
};

int main(){    
    B   b[]={3,4.23,'A',123,123L,23.340,700};
    void *t=&b[0];
    void *n=&b[0]+7;
    while(t!=n){        
        cout<<t<<endl;
        t++;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i dont know if it is correct code and also here is errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  tests.cpp
1>c:\users\7\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tests\tests\tests.cpp(16): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
1>c:\users\7\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tests\tests\tests.cpp(22): error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

please help

Comment: What do you think this code does? I've a horrible suspicion you think you're iterating over each member of that structure with that +7 and for loop. You're not. Also, you've said t is a pointer to void so the compiler doesn't know what size to increment by for the t++ - these should be pointers-to-B, maybe, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, most of your questions are getting down-voted. You really should consider trying to word them so it's clearer what you are asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot increment a void pointer (the last instruction in the while loop), because the compiler cannot know by how much it has to be increased.

The address of structure elements can be taken as for normal variables using the `&` operator:

```
std::cout << "Address of b.k: " << (void*)&b.k << std::endl
```

To get the offset of a member, use the [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/) macro.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct B{
    int k;
    float t;
    char s;
    unsigned int m;
    long q;
    double x;
    unsigned long z;
};

int main()
{
    B b={3,4.23,'A',123,123L,23.340,700};

    std::cout << "Address of b: " << (void*)&b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of k:  " << offsetof(B, k) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of t:  " << offsetof(B, t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of s:  " << offsetof(B, s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of m:  " << offsetof(B, m) << std::endl;
    // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`4.23` is by default a double. You could specify `4.23F` to remove your first warning. See [this reference on literal constants](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html).

Using `t++` to increment a pointer to an element of unknown type is a waste of time. You will never succeed doing this.

What you can do is implement a method in your structure that will print, one by one, the addresses of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operations on structures (`void *n=&b[0]+7;`) is dangerous: you can't be sure how the compiler will align and pack the structure's fields.

Also you can't use pointer arithmetic on a void pointer (`t++;`).

Better, even if not very "object oriented", would be:

```
B* pB = &b[0] + sizeof(B) * 7;
```

Comment: No, he wants t and n to point resp. to the first and last element of his structure in the stack, not to point to 7 structure units forward.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic in C and C++ is defined in array elements, not in bytes. As `b` is an array of `B` objects, `&b[0]+7` yields the 8-th element of the array (if it exists). `&b[0]+ sizeof(B)*7` results in an array element that is `7*sizeof(B)` elements further along in the `b` array.